# Programmatically add HealthIndicator to Liveness and Readiness health group

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to add my custom HealthIndicator to the Liveness and Readiness health group in Spring Boot 3.
I know that there's a `management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include` property to do that. But is there a way to do it programmatically? E.g. define some customizer for the liveness health group bean and add my custom HealthIndicator.

Thank you

I tried defining just the HealthIndicator as a Bean and expecting it to affect the liveness and readiness group, but it doesn't.